# C++ functor / predicate compiletime error - std::sort call results in "identifier not found"

Tags: c++, sorting, predicate, functor

Working on a personal project between terms and totally stuck. Any help is appreciated. None of this is covered in any of my books so I searched in help documentation, discovered predicates, then searched online for how to use the third parameter to sort. The third argument won't compile. I've also tried doing this is a free function, which also doesn't compile, but this is as close as I can get.

Compiletime error "identifier not found" is noted in comment below. Also I've omitted a ton of code; if I comment out the one line then I have no errors and every other method call and functionality works fine, including using the list.sort() call which utilizes the overridden global operator<() I believe.

```
class StudyCategory
{
private:
    std::string label;
    std::list<StudyItem> studyItems;
public:
    // Constructors etc. omitted
    void sortByStartDate();
    void sortByEndDate();
};
      /*
      ***** Compile time error "GreaterEndDate identifier not found" ****
      */

void StudyCategory::sortByEndDate()
{
    std::sort(studyItems.begin(), studyItems.end(), GreaterEndDate());
}
```

I included in the same file the following predicate function, which by all my documentation, seems to be correct and does compile fine:

```
class GreaterEndDate
{
public:
    bool operator() (const StudyItem& a, const StudyItem& b) const
    {
        return a.getEndDate() < b.getEndDate();
    }
};
```

And the StudyItem class has overloaded comparison operators set up as friends of the class. This may not be perfect but it's how the textbook I'm using works.

```
class StudyItem
{
private:
    int startDate, endDate;
public:
    int getStartDate() const;
    int getEndDate() const;
    void setStartDate(int date);
    void setEndDate(int date);

    // Overloaded operators
    friend bool operator==(StudyItem a, StudyItem b);
    friend bool operator<(StudyItem a, StudyItem b);
    friend bool operator>(StudyItem a, StudyItem b);
};

// Friend functions - operator overrides

bool operator==(StudyItem a, StudyItem b)
{
    return a.getStartDate() == a.getStartDate();
}

bool operator<(StudyItem a, StudyItem b)
{
    return a.getStartDate() < a.getStartDate();
}

bool operator>(StudyItem a, StudyItem b)
{
    return a.getStartDate() > a.getStartDate();
}
```

Comment: Something tells me that the definition of `GreaterEndDate` comes after the definition of `StudyCategory::sortByEndDate()`. It needs to come before.. That's why it is important to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Or you can put the declaration before.  Header files and separate source files are great for this.

Comment: I've got separate source files and header files for everything EXCEPT this small class because, well, I'm an idiot! Thanks, I'm sure once I fire up the compiler and put in my appropriate includes and move it into it's own file it will be fine.